# Can't read SD card in digital camera, but can read the card in cardreader

Tags: mount, sd-card, exfat

When I connected the camera with the SD card to my PC, I got the following error messages:

> Error mounting /dev/sdg1 at /media/chef/3831-6263: Command-line `mount -t "exfat" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,iocharset=utf8,namecase=0,errors=remount-ro,umask=0077" "/dev/sdg1" "/media/chef/3831-6263"' exited with non-zero exit status 1: stdout:` FUSE exfat 1.1.0
> '
> stderr: `ERROR: file system is larger than underlying device: 63847792640 > 63847792128.

But when I took the SD card out and put it into card reader, it's fine to read the contents.

I did `sudo apt-get install exfat-fuse exfat-utils` already.

I'm using Ubuntu 15.04. When I was using 14.04. it just working fine with the card in the camera.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in exfat-fuse. It is fixed in newer versions of exfat (https://github.com/relan/exfat). I don't know when this version will end up in Ubuntu. It's not in 15.10 yet at least.

I patched `libexfat/mount.c` with the change in github, which changes the error to a warning.
I.e. from (row 255, or so):

```c
    if (le64_to_cpu(ef->sb->sector_count) * SECTOR_SIZE(*ef->sb) >
          exfat_get_size(ef->dev))
    {
        free(ef->zero_cluster);
        exfat_error("file system is larger than underlying device: "
                "%"PRIu64" > %"PRIu64,
                le64_to_cpu(ef->sb->sector_count) * SECTOR_SIZE(*ef->sb),
                exfat_get_size(ef->dev));
        exfat_close(ef->dev);
        free(ef->sb);
        return -EIO;
    }
```

to

```c
    if (le64_to_cpu(ef->sb->sector_count) * SECTOR_SIZE(*ef->sb) >
            exfat_get_size(ef->dev))
    {
        /* this can cause I/O errors later but we don't fail mounting to let
           user rescue data */
        exfat_warn("file system is larger than underlying device: "
                "%"PRIu64" > %"PRIu64,
                le64_to_cpu(ef->sb->sector_count) * SECTOR_SIZE(*ef->sb),
                exfat_get_size(ef->dev));
    }
#endif
```

In order to get this do:

```
sudo apt-get source exfat-fuse
cd fuse-exfat-1.1.0/
```

edit `libexfat/mount.c` as described above

```
sudo apt-get build-dep exfat-fuse
dpkg-buildpackage -rfakeroot -uc -b
sudo dpkg -i ../exfat-fuse_1.1.0-2_amd64.deb
```

And you're done and can mount the SD-card as expected.

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to compile and install the latest version of exFAT. This is how I did that.

```
sudo apt-get install libfuse-dev
git clone https://github.com/relan/exfat.git
cd exfat/
autoreconf --install
./configure --prefix=/usr
sudo make install
sudo mount.exfat-fuse /dev/sdc1 /media/pd/
```